# How to hide "gaps" between parts of my detail?

Tags: modeling, rendering

Blender 2.81
I created this detail from little several parts (see first pic.). Joined them with Ctrl+J. See one whole detail in Solid.
But in Render i see lines ("gaps") between all this parts (3rd pic.).
How to get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sems you have have overlapping vertices, which creates a seam in the topology when rendering.

Notice the black line between the edges which cause problem in edit mode are darker than the other ones.
Select all your vertices with  <kbd>A</kbd>  in edit mode and vertex select mode, and Press  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  +  <kbd>M</kbd>  (or right click > Merge vertices) then choose "by distance" in order to eliminate double-vertices.

Comment: Did like you said. "Removed 14 verticies" was the message. Center line dissapeared, but horizontal are still here.
http://prntscr.com/qtg9b6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gorgious found the solution.
1) In Edit mode select needed verticies, press X and delete all hidden useless Faces.
2) Select verticies and press F to add new Face at one side.
3) Repeat on all sides.
4) ???
5) Profit.
[image]

Comment: Oh, right, you had overlapping vertices AND faces !

Comment: @Gorgious thanks for tipping. You've driven me to the right way)